# Is a websites downtime a DNS problem if you can ping and traceroute the domains successfully?

Tags: http, dns, hosting, ping, traceroute

I've been with a web host for 10 years and their hosting is good.  I have 12 clients hosted on one account, all with low traffic.

I upgraded to a better package as mine was being phased out.  They promised no downtime.  It's now almost 48 hours and all sites have been down since the migration.

In the 3 chats I've had with support they have agreed the downtime (12, 24, and 36 hours roughly each time) was excessive and they had a known issue.  Each support person said the same thing: "It takes time for DNS to propagate, I have escalated your ticket, This is a known issue, I have pushed the DNS again, just wait 4 hours."

I said this didn't make sense to me because:

1. It is the same host
2. It is the same dedicated IP address
3. It uses the same DNS servers
4. If I ping any of the 12 domains they resolve to the right IP and give me good ms responses
5. If I traceroute any of the 12 domains they resolve to the right IP and show me reasonable hops
6. If I connect through HTTP I get a standard parking page with ads

I've told them this each time and asked if maybe it's not an internal switching problem.  They told me not to worry and it would be resolved soon, it's a DNS issue.

What do I not understand about DNS that justifies their assertion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "It takes time for DNS to propagate," Anyone saying that shows immediately it is clueless about DNS. There is no propagation in DNS. It is not a top down model for changes.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like public DNS issue, but their own internal one, albeit it is a bit excessive.

My bet is that they have internal issue.